# Unable to get contents in javascript file in Odoo 9

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

I've tried to get html contents from javascript declared in my module.

But All I can get by class name is header contents but kanban view.

```
openerp.my_module = function(instance) {
    var header = $(".headerClass").html();
    console.log(header);
    var kanban = $(".kanbanClass").html();
    console.log(kanban);
};
```

also I added the javascript file to web.assets_backend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/my_module.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

first log shows the html contents but second log shows undefined.

I guess when this javascript executed the kanban view in xml doesn't included.

**UPDATE**

```
<record id="my_module_view_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.module.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">my.module.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban class="oe_background_grey o_kanban_dashboard" display="[name]">
             <field name="name"/>
             <field name="color"/>
             <field name="state"/>
             <field name="nth_week"/>
             <field name="date_start"/>
             <field name="date_end"/>
             <field name="date"/>
             <field name="count_employees"/>
             <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                   <div class="kanban_weekly_record">
                      <div t-attf-class="#{kanban_color(record.color.raw_value)} oe_kanban_global_click">
                          <div class="o_weekly_kanban_main">
                             <div class="o_kanban_card_content o_visible">
                                 <div class="o_kanban_primary_left">
                                     <div class="o_kanban_primary_left">
                                         <div class="o_primary weekly">
                                             <span>
                                                 <div class="kanbanClass">
                                                     <t t-esc="record.field.value"/>
                                                 </div>
                                             </span>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </t>
             <template>
         </kanban>
     </field>
</record>
```

Also I get "undefined" when logging with o_kanban_primary_left class.

Answer (score 0):

wait the app to finish loading first before executing this code:

```
openerp.my_module = function(instance) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var header = $(".headerClass").html();
       console.log(header);
       var kanban = $(".kanbanClass").html();
       console.log(kanban);
    });
};
```

as you might have selected a element that hasn't been finished loading yet.

Comment: It still show log before rendering the kanban view. Is there any prerequisites I have to do?

Comment: I cannot guess but where did this `.kanbanClass` element come from?

Comment: It's located at kanban view like project name on Project Kanban View. I will update some more xml file for you